# Router-level middleware order using Express.js

Tags: rest, express, router, middleware

I have the following routers:

```
/* GET /users/username */
router.get("/:username", function(req, res, next) {
  User.findOne({
    username: req.params.username
  }).exec(function(err, user) {
    if (err) return next(error);
    res.json(user);
  });
});

/* GET /users/id */
router.get("/:id", function(req, res, next) {
  User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(user);
  });
});
```

In the above order, `/* GET /users/id */` will return null, and if I swap the order the `/* GET /users/username */` will result in this error:

> Cast to ObjectId failed for value "Guest" at path "_id" for model "User"

Basically, the second middleware is being ignored. However, both are needed for different behaviors. I'm using `AngularJS $resource` to interact with RESTful server-side data sources.

1. Why can't I use both simultaneously? Why is the second middleware ignored?
2. In which order should these two routers be to both working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second middleware is ignored, because the url pattern is the same... How do you want the router make the differenciation between an 'username' or an 'id';

You've got to check if it's an id first per exemple.

```
router.get("/:username", function(req, res, next) {
  const username = req.params.username;
  if (!isNaN(parseInt(username)) {     // <------ Check if it's an ID
     next();
  } else {
  User.findOne({
    username: req.params.username
  }).exec(function(err, user) {
    if (err) return next(error);
    res.json(user);
  });
   }
});

/* GET /users/id */
router.get("/:id", function(req, res, next) {
  User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(user);
  });
});
```

Comment: I see. that's right, the url pattern is the same. I've tested your solution, and it seems working fine. However, one minor issue is, what if the username is an Integer? Is there any alternative to check the username/ID type, e.g. Mongo Object for ID?

Comment: The other solution is really to set a specific pattern to your id route : `/connectById/:id`

Answer (score 0):

It's better to route by doing:
router.route('your/route').get(aJsFile.function);

Then, instead of the exec, just write
attributes: ['id', 'username']
where: {username: username}
Or something like this.